# Implementing WNS (Azure) in a Windows Golang App

Tags: windows, azure, go, push-notification, wns

I'm working on a Windows application in Golang and am exploring the possibility of implementing Windows Push Notification Services (WNS) through Azure. I would like to know if it's feasible to integrate WNS with a Golang application on Windows.

1. Is it possible to implement WNS in a Golang application running on Windows?
2. How can I obtain the ChannelURI required for sending push notifications to Windows devices from Azure?
3. What are the necessary handlers or libraries in Golang that I can use to receive push notifications from WNS in my Windows Golang application?
   I appreciate any insights, code examples, or references that could guide me in implementing WNS functionality in my Golang application.

Thank you in advance for your help!